# Extract the list of GIT branches that are older than specified time period

Tags: git, shell, bitbucket, git-bash

I am using the below GIT command to extract the list of branches along with committer name and date. 
But, wanted to know how to get the branches that were older than 90 days instead of getting the entire list.

```
git for-each-ref --count=10 --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes/ --format='%(refname:short) = %(committerdate:short) =%(committername) =%(authorname)'| xargs -L1 | cut -d"/" -f2- >> $allbrancheslist.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

# 90 days = 7776000 seconds
INTERVAL=7776000

git for-each-ref refs/remotes | while read commit type ref;do
    current=$(date +%s)
    headcd=$(git log -1 --pretty=%cd --date=format:%s ${commit})
    if [[ $((current-headcd)) -ge ${INTERVAL} ]];then
        echo $ref
    fi
done
```

Get the current date and the commit date of each ref's head in the format of epoch. Calculate the interval and print the refs whose interval is greater than or equal to 7776000 seconds.

Comment: is there a way where we can limit it while taking the branches extract itself instead of controlling it after the complete list checkout.

Comment: @user3781945 Sorry, I don't understand your question. The script doesn't need to checkout any branch.

Comment: Getting the below error while trying the execute the provided script            
                                                                                                                      
date: extra operand ‘%s’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
fatal: invalid strftime format: '%s'

Comment: @user3781945 I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. Run `date --help` to see if your `date` has any option to get the epoch.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log -1 --pretty=%cd --date=format:%s ${commit}
```

The OP mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253714/extract-the-list-of-git-branches-that-are-older-than-specified-time-period#comment95438739_54254201):

> ```
> Getting the below error while trying the execute the provided script date: 
> extra operand ‘%s’ Try 'date --help' for more information. 
>
> fatal: invalid strftime format: '%s'
> ```

That means Windows, and this is fixed with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

See [commit 3efc128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3efc128cd59fefb6aa159548d0cf7666ce5e34a9) (09 Apr 2020), and [commit b6852e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6852e19794245566f7c961a434c56ca3b7a883b) (08 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit a748f3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a748f3f3dc0adff1d8a83dfc098ed819658998d0) (08 Apr 2020) by [Matthias Aßhauer (`rimrul`)](https://github.com/rimrul).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b3eb70e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3eb70e0f8988dbf36f42e0bea201e2cd71f248e), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a748f3f3dc0adff1d8a83dfc098ed819658998d0): use modern strftime implementation if possible
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthias Aßhauer</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> Microsoft introduced a new "**Universal C Runtime Library**" (**`UCRT`**) with Visual Studio 2015.
>   The UCRT comes with a **new `strftime()` implementation** that supports more date formats.
>   We link git against the older "Microsoft Visual C Runtime Library" (MSVCRT), so to use the `UCRT strftime()` we need to load it from `ucrtbase.dll` using `DECLARE_PROC_ADDR()/INIT_PROC_ADDR()`.
>
> Most supported Windows systems should have received the UCRT via Windows update, but in some cases only MSVCRT might be available.
>   In that case we fall back to using that implementation.
>
> With this change, it is possible to use e.g. the `%g` and `%V` date format specifiers, e.g.
>
> ```
> git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:‘%g.%V’ HEAD
> ```
>
> Without this change, the user would see this error message on Windows:
>
> ```
> fatal: invalid strftime format: '‘%g.%V’'
> ```
>
> This fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2495](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2495) "Missing support for ISO 8601 date formats"